# In python, how do I write columns of a CSV file to a dictionary?

Tags: python, csv, nameerror

I am trying to take a given csv file and define the first column as the keys, whereas each key refers to an array of 2 values, where one value is in the second column and the other value is in the third column. In the end, it is not an option to switch the columns into rows and vice versa, seeing as how I have literally hundreds of rows in each csv that I have to work with. When I looked online, the only help I could find used syntax with rows, is there any way to work with columns?

Here is the code I was trying:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv'))

result = {}
for row in reader:
    key = column0
    if key in result:
        pass
    result[key] = column1 and column2

print result
```

And the csv I am testing (test.csv):

```
g1_and_g2, 0.04286547, -1.45
g2_and_g2, 0.12348197, 3.00
g3_and_g4, 0.03125879, 1.89
```

When I run the program in terminal, I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'g1_and_g2' is not defined
```

I am pretty new to programming, so any help given is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT to add more information:
The expected output should just be a dictionary that's like:

```
g1_and_g2: 0.04286547,-1.45
g2_and_g2: 0.12348197, 3.00
g3_and_g4: 0.03125879, 1.89
```

So essentially, the strings in the first column should be the keys, and the integers in the second two columns should be values associated with the key in that row.

In addition, I am running python 2.7

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code at all. I suspect you've modified the cost for this question to the point that it isn't representative of your problem.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output? That would help.

Comment: What behavior do you want if a key is repeated in the file? Also, what version of Python are you using? There are some shorthand notations in later versions of Python that could be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reading your description I understand your goal to be to open a csv file in which the first item of every line is a column title/key, and the subsequent items are values for cells in the row corresponding to that key. You'd then like to load this all into a dictionary?

This should do something like what you are looking for if that specification is right.

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    result = {}

    for row in reader:
        key = row[0]
        result[key] = row[1:]

    print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! This is definitely a much better and cleaner solution than what I was trying to do.

Comment: If this approach is generally correct, and you're using 2.7, a more concise implementation is `result = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in reader}`

Comment: I like it Peter. I think there's a good argument for steering away from density of expression with newer programmers. The benefits of short, terse code are less relevant when someone is just figuring out what the moving parts do.